# Loading web pages in Desktop application

Tags: java, .net, ios, blackberry

As i am good in HTML and CSS, I want to make desktop application and mobile apps on one platform so that it will load an HTML page at runtime. My second purpose of doing that is, because if i update the webpage, the desktop application automatically gets updated.

I will prefer java because it can be used across multiple platform. I wants to render the page as Google Chrome renders it.

I want to make all types of application as a desktop application

- Windows
- Mac

I also wants to make all kinds of mobile application

- Android
- BlackBerry OS
- iOS
- Symbian OS
- Java Mobile Application

Any platform welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should look at JEditorPane..

Comment: *"As i am good in HTML and CSS, I want to make desktop application in Java so that it will load an HTML page at runtime."*  What does the web page do?  If it is 1) Simple HTML/CSS 2) just for display and 3) does not require interaction beyond following links, ..then `JEditorPane` as suggested, might be sufficient.  **However** note that I suspect you are after more complicated effects from the HTML than an editor pane can easily provide.  Further, there are better ways to update a desktop application than have them download a web page each run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has classes that can render basic html.

If you want something better you have to use a web browser. I would probably go with QtJambi and Webkit.

Comment: I tried `JEditorPane`, I wants to load web page as it is. `JEditorPane` is not good enough. In java, do we have such plugins so that HTML can be render as browser.

Comment: Check this [link](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2008/01/11/who-needs-a-browser-qt-jambi-just-got-one/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a JEditorPane to view a web page.

try this:

```
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class OReillyHomePage {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
     jep.setEditable(false);   

     try {
       jep.setPage("http://www.oreilly.com");
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
       jep.setContentType("text/html");
       jep.setText("<html>Could not load http://www.oreilly.com </html>");
     } 

     JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep);     
     JFrame f = new JFrame("O'Reilly & Associates");
     // Next line requires Java 1.3
     f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
     f.setSize(512, 342);
     f.show();

  }

}
```

reference:
[Using a JEdtiroPane to dispaly a web page](http://www.cafeaulait.org/slides/iw2000/whatsnew/07.html)

Comment: Some more tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html HyperlinkListener: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what ui toolkit you were going to use.  The default would be to Swing and if you want to go that route then I would recommend [DJ Native Swing](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/).  It gives you a true native browser that can be embedded into your application.

Another choice is to use SWT which has a browser component build right into the toolkit.  Take a look at the [Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html) or this [simple tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html).

Comment: When i talk about the desktop app, best example is skype application. So i just wants to reach on that level.

Comment: Then I would go with SWT since the browser component is built into the toolkit and well supported.